# How to redirect after user register according to radio button wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to redirect page after user registers i created two radio button paynow and pay later in user register i want to redirect when the user clicks paynow user should register and redirect to custom url and if the user select pay later user should register and send  custom url to user for future payment here is the code i used

```
    $myemail=$_POST['email'];
        $first_name="firstname";
         $last_name="lastname";


    echo "<script>window.location.href='https://www.payumoney.com/?firstname=$first_name&last_name=$last_name'&email=$myemail'</script>";


    $to="test@gmail.com";   
    $message = "
    Please payus for registering account https://www.payumoney.com/?firstname=$first_name&last_name=$last_name'&email=$email'
    ";

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: madu<test@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: madu<test@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";


    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }

    }
    add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_19692_registration_redirect' );


Radio buttons
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

        ?>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="paystatus" id="paystatus" value="paynow">Pay Now<br>
             <input type="radio" name="paystatus"  id="paystatus" value="paylater">Pay Later
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    //2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
    function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

        if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
            $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
        }

        return $errors;
    }

    //3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
    add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
    function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['paystatus'] ) ) {
           $checkme= update_user_meta( $user_id, 'paystatus', trim( $_POST['paystatus'] ) );
        }


    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user through JavaScript depending on the $_POST value of your radio:

```
// example radio name: "payment_time"
// redirect to this url if value equals to "pay_now"
if(isset($_POST['payment_time']) && $_POST['payment_time'] == 'pay_now'):
?> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://url1.com";
    </script>
<?php elseif(isset($_POST['payment_time']) && $_POST['payment_time'] == 'pay_later'): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://url2.com";
    </script>
<?php
endif;
```

And on the frontend, create a form with the radios:

```
<input type="radio" id="pay_now" name="payment_time" value="pay_now"><label for="pay_now"> Pay now</label>
<input type="radio" id="pay_later" name="payment_time" value="pay_later"><label for="pay_later"> Pay later</label>
```

Comment: Its not working i added  two radio buttons in wordpress registration fields  i want to redirect for that

Comment: So please post your whole code. The radio form and all the processing code. Make sure you separate each code block so its better readable. I also just saw, that you named the radios "paystatus"... The name of the radios will be the key name in the $_POST array like in my example.